# Data Structure - Tree - what this function doing

Tags: java, function, recursion, tree

I have this 2 functions:

```
// Return the smallest number
public static int min (int a, int b) { ... }

// Return is the Node is Leaf
public static boolean isLeaf (Node t) { ... }
```

What does this function do:

```
public static int f (Node t)
{
   if (t == null)
   return 0;
   return 1 + min (f (t.getLeftSon()),f (t.getRightSon()));
}
```

Comment: What do you think it does? Homework? To me it looks like the lowest subtree height.

Comment: Try to draw a tree and see how this recursive method behave and what it does.

Comment: i already try but the recursive very confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method traverses a **binary tree** represented by the `Node` object recursively and returns the height of its smallest subtree. If the tree only has a root it will return `1`.

Answer (score -2):

This function recursively call itself and when its value becomes null it stops.. Then, iteratively callback and calculate something. This calculation is maximum height of three..

Comment: Exactly how can it involve a maximum of anything by calling `min`?

Comment: Exactly how is this generic description can be an answer to this question?